# flutter simple permissions android version compare and iOS path_provider error

Tags: dart, flutter

I am used Flutter Simple Permissions plugin in my app but I have a some issues with it.

1.) When i run app on android 6 and higher version there is no problem but when i run it on android 5 execution stopped on "**SimplePermissions.checkPermission**" and only 
showing console message "**Checking permission: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**"  so my question is that how to compare android version in flutter?

2.) how to determine if the user checked “**Never ask again**”? and ask for open app settings

3.) Error with iOS permissions "**BUILD TARGET path_provider OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug**"

Console Message:   === BUILD TARGET path_provider OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /Users/home/Library/Android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_permissions-0.1.9/ios/Classes/SimplePermissionsPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'simple_permissions/simple_permissions-Swift.h' file not found
    #import 
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.

I am new with flutter so please help me if any one know about it. Thanks advanced.

Comment: 1st and 2nd points are solved by myself please help me for 3rd point

Answer (score 0):

please try this edits in Podfile Code needs to be added or edited are marked with "** ...... **"

```
target 'Runner' do
  ** use_frameworks!  **
```

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
          ** config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0' **
        end
      end
    end
```

delete your Podfile.lock and try